# IPv6 routing in Routing & Remote Access Services VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, windows-server-2012, ipv6, rras

I am trying to configure IPv6 IP Pool on Microsoft RRAS VPN Server the RRAS server is assigning the IPv6 IP Address to the remote access clients but when I test the IPv6 address assignment from "test-ipv6.com/" it says "No IPv6 address detected" inspite that the RRAS server is assigning the IPv6 address to connected clients. A brief info of my config .

IPv6 Pool : 2602:ff84:1::

IPV6 IP on server Network Adaptor : 2602:ff84:1::2/64

Gateway on IPv6 interface on server : 2602:ff84:1::1

IPv6 Pool on RRAS : 2602:ff84:1::

"Enable IPv6 Forwarding" Checkbox selected in RRASVPN server
"Enable Default route advertisement" Checkbox selected in RRASVPN server

Clients are assigned the IPv6 IP address from the RRAS server pool. When I try to ping the IPv6 address assigned to server (2602:ff84:1::2) ping responds but when I try to ping the gateway set on the server (2602:ff84:1::1) ping doesn't responds and show connection time out. Any ideas what could be the problem.

Any help is highly appreciated..
Thanks
Frank

Comment: Have you looked at the routes? For instance `Get-NetRoute -AddressFamily IPv6` And try a traceroute, e.g. `tracert -d -6 www.google.com`

Comment: When I take tracert to google from the client side the first hop it shows is the the IP of the internal interface(RAS (Dial In) Interface) of the RRAS server after that the packet drops.....

Comment: That suggests that either the RRAS server isn't forwarding, or it doesn't have IPv6 connectivity configured properly for itself.

Comment: Exactly you are right ........When I tracert -6 google.com from server the response is normal I can also ping the IPv6 address of google.com from server the IPV6 connectivity is fine at the RRAS server but from the client this wierd problem is coming.....by the way what do you suggest in this case....
I am having the same exact issue this user has on the technet

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/575e83fb-5f6e-401f-bf9b-e6f09fbf0f16/pptp-vpn-with-rras-2008-server-in-ipv6-enviroment?forum=ipv6

Comment: Any suggestions...????

Comment: I suggest editing your question.

Comment: ok what editing should I make do I post the snapshots of the routing tables etc...???